# regex - capture group

Tags: regex

I trying to write a regex to match the following at the beginning of a new line
 - a number followed by parantheses e.g. 2) or 8)
 - a number followed by period e.g. 5 
 - the character '-'
 - the character '*'

the following strings should match

- "1. Sorting function. If you have a long checklist it's very difficult."
- "5) This is another example"
- "-this is yet another one"
- "* last item in the list"

I have tried this  but it doesn't quite get me what I am looking for.

```
re.findall(r'(?m)\s*^[-*(\d.)(\d\))]',item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
re.findall(r'^\s*(\d+(\)|\.)|-|\*)', item, re.MULTILINE)
```

It will match all sequences of numbers followed by a closing parenthesis or period as well as dashes and stars at the *beginning of the line*.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/cR2lZ5/6

Comment: it does not match the * and - characters.

Comment: Nice regex, but I have a couple suggestions: Why do you use alternation instead of a bracket expression? Wouldn't `[\)\.\*-]` be clearer than `(\)|\.)|\*|-`? Similarly, since this is Python, what about a negative lookbehind at the beginning of the regex, which would leave you with something like `(?<!\()(\d+[\)\.\*-])`?

Comment: I try to avoid lookaheads/behinds if possible, but your bracket expression is an excellent point. Will update answer.

Comment: Actually the alternation is required, because `5*` is not valid, as your suggestion would allow - assuming you've suggested `\d+[\)\.\*-]`

Comment: @MartinKonecny    https://regex101.com/r/cR2lZ5/5 I want to match only if the desired characters appear at the beginning of a new line (I will update the original question). here it matches things like 2.99 etc and others mid-sentence

Comment: @MartinKonecny: *I try to avoid lookaheads/behinds if possible* - so, you think a lookahead is a worse construct than, say, a lazy dot matching? Do you think `And.*?now` is a more efficient regex than `And[^n]*(?:n(?!ow)[^n]*)*now`?

Comment: no, but it's definitely more readable. Yours definitely wins performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your quote marks " are not included, and that each line is a separate string,

```
^\d\.|^\d\)|^\-|^\*
```

Would be the regular expression. | is OR, \d is a digit, and you escape the special characters ".", ")", "-", and "*" by putting a backslash in front of them.

You can test your regular expressions [here](https://regex101.com/). Good luck!